# How to get the list of 'Bikes' based on 'Station' Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my `Station` model i have declared a `List<Bikes> bikes{get;set;}` in order for each station to have its own set of bikes. Declaring that way in my `Bikes` Database table i have the `StationId`. I didn't find any way of how to get only the bikes from one station based on the stationid.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do that?

Here is my `Station` Model:

```
public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Denumire")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Longitudine")]
    public double Longitudine { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Latitudine")]
    public double Latitudine { get; set;}
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cate biciclete sunt in statie")]
    public int NrOfBikes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cate biciclete sunt disponibile in statie")]
    public int NrOfAvailableBikes { get; set; }
    public List<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Este inchisa?")]
    public bool isClosed { get; set; }        
}
```

And here is my Bike model:

```
public class Bike
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

What I've tried so far:
The station id is coming as a parameter in the method:

```
List<Bike> bikes = new List<Bike>();
var stations = _context.Stations.Where(x=>x.Id == id);

bikes = _context.Stations.Where(x => x.Bikes. "????" == stations.Id);
```

Here is what my `Station` table looks like:

[image]

And here is what my `Bikes` table looks like:

[image]

I'm having trouble into replacing "????" with something useful in order to get only the bikes from the current station.

NOTE: I'm using SQL Server LocalDB and the tabels are created with EF.

Comment: What database tools are you using? i.e. how are you getting from the database to the model? Are you using EF, for example? or raw ADO.NET? or dapper? or a data-adapter? or any of 200 other options? this is very important (much more so than the fact that it is asp.net, for example); also: "because what I've tried didn't gave the expected result." - showing what you've tried would perhaps be useful here, so we can infer context

Comment: Please share database tables and models to have better understanding.

Comment: Okei, got it, updating the question now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid using third party services to show images. If you need to add images, add them to the post by either clicking the image button while editing, or copying the image and clicking CTRL+V, or in any other way pasting it) directly into the post. Third party image services [can break at any time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354950/6296561), and either leave a dead link, or the URLs can be used for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to query all bikes for a given station, you don't need to query the stations table.

If your foreign keys and navigation objects are properly set up, you could:

```
var station = context.Stations.Include(s => s.Bikes).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == stationId);
// TODO: null check on station
var bikes = station.Bikes;
```

If you don't have that Bikes navigation property, query the Bikes table directly:

```
var bikes = context.Bikes.Where(b => b.StationId == stationId).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, the first pice of code worked as expected. I tryed querying the Bikes Table directly as you mentiond, at least 10 times, but it didn't want to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable` so with this line of code:-

```
var stations = _context.Stations.Where(x => x.Id == id);
```

you are getting an `IEnumerable` of `Station` but I am assuming you only want one `Station` where the `StationId` matches. For that you can do:-

```
var station = _context.Stations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

once you have the `station` you can do `station.Bikes` to get the list of `bikes` particular to this `station`

also make sure to check for `null` on `station` before performing any operation on it because `FirstOrDefault` will return null in case a matching element is not found

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful indeed. Thanks a mili!